# Can I make http redirect using 403 ( forbidden )?

Tags: scala, redirect, playframework

I'm developing an application with Play! Framework. When I have to do a redirect passing http status with code 403 ( forbidden ), the redirect doesn't work, but when I do with 303 ( see other ) works fine.

It's my code:

```
Future.successful( play.api.mvc.Results.Redirect("http://otherDomain", 
                            play.api.http.Status.FORBIDDEN)
                  .discardingCookies( DiscardingCookie("key") ))
```

Any idea ?!

I'm using:

Scala 2.10 and Play! Framework 2.3.3

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with how browsers handle redirects. There's a set of redirect codes, you can read about them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx. When browser sees such a code, it looks at the response's `Location` header, which contains the website to perform redirect to. And does the redirect. When, however, the status code is not the one of the redirect (say, 403), the browser doesn't try to redirect you, even if the `Location` header is present. Therefore, you should use a correct response code (say, 302 'found' or `play.api.http.Status.FOUND`) to perform redirects.

Comment: I understood everthing. I've found something in Play's documentation and code about this topic. Thanks so much!